# Rows to Columns gets NULLs in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table (StrategiesUsed):

```
receiverID  strategies       counts            print
--------------------------------------------------------------
14          RationalPositive    12            0
14          EmotionalNegative   4             0
45          EmotionalPositive   17            1
154         RationalPositive    5             1
154         EmotionalPositive   6             1
154         EmotionalNegative   3             1
```

When I Issue the following statement to get "strategies" values as columns:

```
select `receiverID`,
       case when strategies like "EmotionalNegative" then `counts` end as EN,
       case when strategies like "RationalPositive" then `counts` end as EP
from StrategiesUsed
group by receiverID
```

I get:

```
receiverID  EN  EP
14         NULL 12
45         NULL NULL
154        NULL 5
```

Why are there only `NULL`s in the `EN` column? I am doing the exact same thing as I do for `EP` and according to the table, there is a 4 in "EmotionalNegative" for `receiverID` 14 and a 3 for 154.

if I group by strategies in addition to receiverID, I get

```
receiverID  EN  EP
14          4   NULL
14          NULL    12
45          NULL    NULL
154         3   NULL
154         NULL    NULL
154         NULL    5
```

But what I really would like is:

```
receiverID  EN  EP
14          4   12
45         NULL NULL
154        3    5
```

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: Because you have GROUP BY statement and your receiver id's are collapsed to one record each. I suppose you wanted to group by strategies as well.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to reflect what I want better. Grouping by strategies on top of receiverID does not help in the way I need.

Comment: @sashkello Actually, if he groups by that field, then there is no sense to put them in different columns as you will indeed get null values

Comment: Aha, so, you need a pivot table (you can use PIVOT keyword for that or just have SUMs over those CASE things). Your strategies are unique, right?

Comment: @sashkello No, MySQL doesn't support pivots

Comment: @MostyMostacho Yes, that one wouldn't work, you are right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for each receiverID your strategies are unique, then this should do it:

```
select
       `receiverID`,
       SUM(IF(strategies="EmotionalNegative", counts, 0)) as EN,
       SUM(IF(strategies="RationalPositive", counts, 0)) as EP
from StrategiesUsed
group by receiverID
```

Comment: Well, if I add sum to my case statements it also works, although there is nothing to sum. I guess the aggregate function SUM works its magic to group it all in the same row.

Comment: @fiacobelli Yep, it handles NULLs properly and would be equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 2):

After a second read of the question I've just realised you were missing the `ELSE` part of the case statement:

```
case when strategies like "EmotionalNegative" then `counts` else 0 end
```

If you can have more than one strategy of course, add the `SUM`.

Comment: I do not need the sum of the counts. THere is only one count for every pair of receiverID and strategy. However, aggregating columns with SUM seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @fiacobelli Funny thing. It is not the sum. You were missing the `else 0` in your original query. That simple change will do the trick, otherwise when there is no `ELSE` and the condition is not true then a `NULL` is used. There is the explanation :)